# Strange marker tap behavior - need to tap twice

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented a custom overlay marker extending the `OverlayView` class as [explained here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays).

I'm attaching the click handler to the cloned dom element like so:

```
this.el_.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'));
```

Pretty regular stuff.

But for some reason, in mobile device mode, I need to tap twice on it, to actually fire the event. Like it first needs to be focused in order to fire:

[image]